# Share the same database between 2 computers

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, share

My application needs to be deployed in 2 computers, and I save all the data in a database. While working on my pc, I don't have a problem connecting to the database using *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio* for this application but once it needs to be deployed on 2 computers, I don't know how to share the same database between them.

I have a table "User" that collects all the students that were present in one location, and I need to compare this data with students that were present in another location to see if everyone was present in both locations. It's like a tracking application to see if the same user was present in both places.

The problem I'm facing is how to connect the same database between two different computers? Or should I work with 2 databases and 2 application ( one for students who were in one place, and the other for another place) and then use a thrid script to compare the datas that are in the 2 tables?

Hope my question is clear, if you need any details let me know. 
Thank you!

Comment: Run sql server agent  from services and also run in sql server

Comment: If you need your applications to share the same data - you'll have to set up a SQL server instance that can be reached over a network. Either put your database on a centralised server, put it into a hosting like Azure, or configure one of your PCs to become a SQL Server

Comment: And allow the PC to access from anywhere, from my computer properties, you can refer in internet how to make to access my PC remotely

Comment: The two PCs have to be in the same group for data to be shared.  I also setup a user group account and put all users of the database in the group account.  Then I make sure the SQL server database is using a window credential (not an SQL credential) and make the window credential the Group Account with all  the users who need access to the database.